# Orientation broken in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7, uiinterfaceorientation

I have developed an iOS app which support `Orientation` as well. Till `iOS 8.4` it was giving me correct view size (width and Height) in `viewWillAppear` method according to `Orientation` changes. But now I ran my existing app in `Xcode 7` with `iOS 9` then `Orientation` has broken as the view size is not correct if you display it in `viewWillAppear` method. I am updating all controllers of frame through `viewWillAppear` method, but now its not working. Is there any other solution to achieve it. I am using `Xib` without `Autolayout` enabled. Please help me.

Comment: What is the size returned?

Comment: It used to update/give size according Portrait or Landscape, but now its not happening. In viewDidAppear its returning correct size.

Answer (score 1):

Something very similar happened to me and I stumbled upon this question when googling for an answer. 
The issue in my case was because of a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` implementation which failed to assign the proper frame for the new view.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;
    toView.frame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toVC];
    // transition animation goes here...
}
```

I don't know why, but until iOS 9 there wasn't an issue if this line was missing.

Hope it help

Comment: Issue persist on iOS 10.0 and this solution solves it. Thanks.